# Можно ли адаптировать слайдер

Tags: css, width

Здравствуйте. Скачала симпатичный слайдер *hw-slider*:  http://heavenweb.ru/demo/hwslider/index.html (код весь прописан в одной странице). Растянула во всю ширину, прописав в стилях `width:100%` вместо пикселей, и получилось почти то, что мне нужно. Стили и скрипты перенесла в отдельные файлы и подключила в html `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`, чтобы можно было менять слайдер в зависимости от мобильного устройства. Меня не устраивает отображение на маленьких экранах шириной до `420px`, слишком большая высота и часть изображения "съедается". Пробовала вместо ширины задавать высоту в `%`, но тогда изображения вообще исчезли. Комбинации `max-height` и `min-height`, что в пикселях, что в `%` тоже ничего не дали.
Код *css*, где я меняла параметры:

```
#slider-wrap {
   width:100%;
}
#slider {
   width:100%;
   height:360px;
   overflow: hidden;
   position:relative;
   border:#eee solid 10px;
}
@media (max-width:900px){
   #slider-wrap{
      width:97%;    
   }
}
@media (max-width:420px){
   #slider-wrap{
      width:96%;
   }
}
```

Вопрос, можно ли этот слайдер сделать так, чтобы он показывал картинку целиком, вне зависимости от ширины экрана, и в чём моя ошибка? Заранее благодарю за конструктивную критику.

Comment: Можете приложить фотографии, что бы мы видели точно, какие проблемы? Или укажите ссылку на полный ваш код

Comment: Вопрос закрыт.Мне посоветовали перенести весь код в новый файл, а старый удалить.